# I'm trying to use getche() in linux over gcc on the terminal

Tags: c, gcc

I need to know how to compile a program in C with the getche() function, but isn't compilling because it needs a reference. Some one know what reference is missing?

im using this comand:

gcc filename.c -o exec

Comment: What do you mean it "needs a reference"?  Can you paste the exact error message?  (Also, `exec` seems like a poor choice of name, since it is a shell built-in.)

Comment: @andrewdski: I suspect Duracell saw the linker error message "`undefined reference to 'getche'`" and doesn't know what that means.  @Duracell: "undefined reference" is the GNU linker's admittedly less-than-obvious way of telling you that neither any of the files and libraries you listed, nor the system libraries that are included by default, define a function (or global variable) that your program *refers* to.  In this case, that is because `getch[e]` are DOSisms that have never been available for Unix - see my answer for what you ideally *should* use instead, or Dan's for a quick fix.

Answer (score 3):

For Linux and other Unix platforms you probably want to be using [ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) instead of just trying to emulate getch[e].  It's a slightly more involved API but it'll take care of all kinds of gotchas for you, which the simple emulation Dan D. posted won't.  (For instance, it does the Right Thing if the user types <kbd>^C</kbd> or <kbd>^Z</kbd>.)

Answer (score 2):

From http://wesley.vidiqatch.org/code-snippets/alternative-for-getch-and-getche-on-linux/

```
/*
    getch() and getche() functionality for UNIX,
    based on termios (terminal handling functions)

    This code snippet was written by Wesley Stessens (wesley@ubuntu.com)
    It is released in the Public Domain.
*/

#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static struct termios old, new;

/* Initialize new terminal i/o settings */
void initTermios(int echo) {
    tcgetattr(0, &old); /* grab old terminal i/o settings */
    new = old; /* make new settings same as old settings */
    new.c_lflag &= ~ICANON; /* disable buffered i/o */
    new.c_lflag &= echo ? ECHO : ~ECHO; /* set echo mode */
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new); /* use these new terminal i/o settings now */
}

/* Restore old terminal i/o settings */
void resetTermios(void) {
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &old);
}

/* Read 1 character - echo defines echo mode */
char getch_(int echo) {
    char ch;
    initTermios(echo);
    ch = getchar();
    resetTermios();
    return ch;
}

/* Read 1 character without echo */
char getch(void) {
    return getch_(0);
}

/* Read 1 character with echo */
char getche(void) {
    return getch_(1);
}

/* Let's test it out */
int main(void) {
    char c;
    printf("(getche example) please type a letter: ");
    c = getche();
    printf("\nYou typed: %c\n", c);
    printf("(getch example) please type a letter...");
    c = getch();
    printf("\nYou typed: %c\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```